# MATLAB finding max. of a struct

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to find max value of a struct but `max([tracks(:).matrix])` does not work. It gives me the following error: "Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent." Do you have an idea?

Here is what my struct looks like:

```
tracks = 

1x110470 struct array with fields:
    nPoints
    matrix
```

tracks.matrix includes 3D points. For example here is

```
tracks(1,2).matrix:

33.727467   96.522331   27.964357
31.765503   95.983849   28.984663
30.677082   95.989578   29
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array fun, followed by another max to do this:

```
s.x = [1 3 4];
s(2).x = [9 8];
s(3).x = [1];

maxVals = arrayfun(@(struct)max(struct.x(:)),s);

maxMaxVals = max(maxVals(:));
```

Or, if you want to retain the size of .x after MAX:

```
s.x = [1 3 4];
s(2).x = [9 8 3];
s(3).x = [1 2 2; 3 2 3];

maxVals = arrayfun(@(struct)max(struct.x,[],1),s,'uniformoutput',false);

maxMaxVals = max(cat(1,maxVals{:}))
```

Or, if you know everything is n x 3

```
s.x = [1 3 4];
s(2).x = [9 8 3];
s(3).x = [1 2 2; 3 2 3];
matrix = cat(1,s.x)
maxVals = max(matrix)
```

Comment: It's true.  max(arrayfun(@(z)max(z.x(:)),s)) and z = arrayfun(@(z)max(z.x(:)),s); max(z) will both do the same thing.  Not sure the var name matters in this case, since the overload will only be inside the anonymous function.  I often violate that rule for arrayfun and cellfun, e.g., cellfun(@(cell)f(cell),...) but only in that case.  In general, definitely a bad idea to use struct or cell as var names though

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure what you are trying to find the max of, but you can do this:

```
matrixConcat = [tracs.matrix]
```

which will give you a big concatenated list of all the matrices. You can then do max on that to find the maximum.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for otherwise i will change my answer.

Comment: `matrixConcat = [tracks.matrix]
Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.` I also tried tracks(:).matrix But it did not work. I am trying to find the maximum point in the tracks.matrix

Comment: @Amadeus are the matrices differant sizes or are they always 3x3? If they are different then you will have to pad them to the same size as the largest matrix.

Comment: they are not all 3*3. for example tracks(1,1).matrix has 3 elements with 3 coordinates (x,y,z) whereas tracks(1,98098).matrix has 54 elements with 3 coordinates. How can I pad them and find the maximum?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `[]` because the sizes of all `tracks.matrix` are different, hence the concatenation fails.

You *can* however use `{}` to concatenate to cell:

```
% example structure
t = struct(...
    'matrix', cellfun(@(x)rand( randi([1 5])), cell(1, 30), 'uni', 0))


% find the maximum of all these data    
M = max( cellfun(@(x)max(x(:)), {t.matrix}) );
```

Now, if you don't want to find the overall maximum, but the maximum per column (supposing you have (x,y,z) coordinates in each column, you should do

```
% example data
tracks = struct(...
    'matrix', {rand(2,3) rand(4,3)})

% compute column-wise max 
M = max( cat(1, tracks.matrix) )
```

This works because calling `tracks.matrix` when `tracks` is a multi-dimensional structure is equal to expanding the contents of a cell-array:

```
tracks.matrix         % call without capture equates to:

C = {tracks.matrix};  % create cell
C{:}                  % expand cell contents
```

Comment: Under tracks.matrix I have three coordinates, so what can I do if I want to find maximum or minimum of only x coordinate or y coordinate (not minimum or maximum of all the coordinates x,y,z)?