# Same MATLAB code working on R2012a but not on R2009a

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have Matlab R2012a installed on my own computer and Matlab R2009a (multi thread) installed on my friend's computer. Because of the reason that my computer has only 2gb ram whereas my friend's has 128gb and a better processor, I decided to execute my code on my friend's computer.

I connected to his computer with a remote desktop connection program, downloaded my code and dataset from dropbox and executed my code. However, my code's execution did not finish even though an hour passed. (*It took about 20 minutes on my computer and if you think that my friend's system is much more better than mine, it should have taken less than 20 minutes.*) Then I waited a few hours more but execution did not finish.

Then, to understand where the problem is, I evaluated the code step by step by hand and noticed that it could not finish the execution of the following loop:

```
l=1;
for n=1:max_t
    for m=1:t(1,n).numberofPoints
        x_t(l)=t(1,n).matrix(m,1);
        y_t(l)=t(1,n).matrix(m,2);
        z_t(l)=t(1,n).matrix(m,3);
        l=l+1;
    end
end
minx = min(x_t(:));
miny = min(y_t(:));
minz = min(z_t(:));
```

It is just a simple loop to obtain my minimum point in x,y,z coordinates. (*I am sure there is nothing wrong with this loop. It works successfully on my PC.*) I know I do not need loops to obtain maximum and minimum points of a struct but I am new to MATLAB and do not know much. Therefore it seemed like the easiest option to me.

I really have to be able to use my friends' computer because my ram will not be enough for the further process. Therefore I need to solve this problem.

What can be the reason that same code works on my computer but not on my friends' computer?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "it could not finish the following loop"?

Comment: @carlosdc It does not finish the execution of that for loop?

Comment: Amadeus: does it start and suddenly stop? does it not start? does it make progress? how much progress? does it fail with an error? does it finish the inner loop once?

Comment: @carlosdc It does make progress I am pretty sure. Because when I stop the execution by ctrl+C then it is clear that there are elements in the arrays x_t and y_t. It never stopped suddenly. To understand if inner loop finishes, I tried to display a sentence but it did not dipslay it.

Comment: I believe "not finishing" simply means that it does not finish whithin reasonable time. Matlab has made it hurt less when you fail to pre-allocate in more recent versions, but in older versions like R2009a, if you shoot yourself in the foot, you won't be walking quickly through your code any longer.

Comment: I vote to re-open, since the question is an important lesson about changes in internal optimization of Matlab, rather than a problem of a person's computer hardware or software installation, as the original title suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matlab R2011a introduced dramatic performance improvements when [growing arrays in a loop](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/05/16/automatic-array-growth-gets-a-lot-faster-in-r2011a/), and I believe R2012a improved those even further.

Thus, in R2009, the loop simply takes a lot longer to run, since you're not pre-allocating `x_t`.

There are other ways to improve your code as well, here I'll simply fix the preallocation:

```
l=1;

%# preallocate with NaN, so that the values don't interfere with
%# taking the minimum later
lMax = sum([t(1,1:max_t).numberofPoints)]);
[x_t,y_t,z_t] = deal(NaN(lMax,1));

for n=1:max_t
    for m=1:t(1,n).numberofPoints
        x_t(l)=t(1,n).matrix(m,1);
        y_t(l)=t(1,n).matrix(m,2);
        z_t(l)=t(1,n).matrix(m,3);
        l=l+1;
    end
end
minx = min(x_t(:));
miny = min(y_t(:));
minz = min(z_t(:));
```

Comment: But he does the same thing on both machines.  It ran fine when he failed to preallocate on his own machine.  That would explain inefficiency, but not the difference between the two machines.

Comment: @duffymo he's developing in one that does't go so slowly on uninitialized arrays and testing on one that does.

Comment: So you're assuming that they have two different versions of Matlab installed?  If that's true, it's a material difference.  I agree with you in that case.  I don't see that it was said in the original post.  Only CPU and RAM differences were cited, unless I missed them.

Comment: @duffymo: the OP does state that there are two different versions of Matlab (2nd sentence from the top): `I have Matlab R2012a installed on my own computer and Matlab R2009a (multi thread) installed on my friend's computer. ` I've edited the question's title to make it even more apparent.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  That's a key point and I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it won't execute on your friend's computer.  It's obvious that there's something different besides the processor and RAM.

I'd wonder why anyone would code what you did.  You have two loops that load the data into vectors and then you find the min values of x, y, and z.  Why not just find the min values while you're looping over the values?  No need for the calls to min.

I'm not as familiar with Matlab as I'd like, but I'd also wonder why you need to copy out of the matrix to do this.  Matrix rows can be thought of as vectors or arrays.  Couldn't you just search for the min on the x, y, z columns without having to duplicate the data?

Comment: yeah you are right but as I stated in my question: "I know I do not need loops to obtain maximum and minimum points of a struct but I am new to MATLAB and do not know much. Therefore it seemed like the easiest option to me." I copied the arrays because I could not directly apply min or max. Anyways, I was going to search for a more efficient solution to get max and min values. But what I could not understand and wondering the reason why was the interesting thing that the code working on my computer was not working on my friends' computer.

Comment: Yes, you can easily get min and max.  No, you didn't provide enough information to figure out why your friend's computer won't do it.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote is slow for a number of reasons...
you don't preallocate `x_t` and friends, instead you grow them in the loop.
And in the end you do nothing with them but compute their maximum...

I agree with duffymo; why not get rid of the whole double-for-loop and write

```
minx = min( [t(1,:).matrix(:,1)] )
```

or

```
minx = min( cellfun(@(x)min(x(:)), {t(1,:).matrix(:,1)}, 'uni',0) );
```

or some other permutation of those tools that works for your case?

Comment: `minx = min( cellfun(@(x)min(x(:)), {tracks(1,:).matrix(:,1)}, 'uni',0) );
Scalar index required for this type of multi-level indexing.` `minx = min( [tracks(1,:).matrix(:,1)] )
Scalar index required for this type of multi-level indexing.`

Comment: @Amadeus: "or some other permutation of those tools that works for your case"

Comment: @Amadeus: See for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575523/matlab-finding-max-of-a-struct/13578810#comment18875467_13578810

Comment: @Amadeus: oh wait...you're the same guy! :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhius yes I am. my aim was to learn that what could be the reason that a code working on my computer does not work on my friend's computer. I knew that my loop was not efficient but it was the location where the problem occurred. Therefore I put it here. But I guess my question went off the rails.

Comment: @Amadeus: Well, to be frank, this question doesn't show much research effort either...you *could* print out `n` and/or `m` to see how far the loops get, if they are entered at all, you could try and produce a minimal working example (that is, the minimum amount of code *WE* can copy-paste to reproduce the problem), etc.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I admire and encourage your efforts of learning the way you are doing it! I'll be honest: *debugging* any code takes ***WAY*** more effort than writing it. This is true in *any* programming language. You're best off learning how to debug properly in some language, and learn how to code in it along the way :) What I commented above about printing values during execution; that's probably the first thing to do in any debugging process.

Answer (score 0):

Until you develop some fairly basic troubleshooting skills, debugging code (and therefore writing code and programming in general) is going to be very difficult, painful and not enjoyable at all for you. I'm asking you for the upteenth time:

**How much progress does it make? When you stop the execution (i.e. you hit Ctrl-C), what is the value of `l`?**

If the value of l is 1, you may have some issues with Matlab licensing that are manifesting strangely. Try to work on that.

**Is it making progress but going slowly? When you stop the execution what is the `size(x_t)`?**

If the `size(x_t)` is l (or close to l) you have not initialized adequately your array. You should probably take a look at the excellent reply by Jonas.

Frankly, I have already voted to close this question as too localized. Perhaps you should try to fix it in such a way that it shows some effort on your part (other than emphasizing your friend and his machine and his RAM) emphasize actions you've done to fix the problem and their outcome.